# Setting up container registry for kubeflow

Tags: docker, kubeflow

I am using ubuntu 20.04

while following book -> https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kubeflow-for-machine/9781492050117/

on page 17, it says the following (only relevant parts) which I don't understand....

> You will want to store container images called a
> container registry. The container registry will be accessed by your Kubeflow cluster.

I am going to use docker hub as container registry. Next

> we'll assume that you've set your container registry via an environment variable
> $CONTAINER_REGISTRY, in your shell" NOTE: If you use registry that isn't on Google Cloud
> Platform, you will need to configure Kubeflow pipelines container builder to have access to
> your registry by following the Kaniko configuration guide -> https://oreil.ly/88Ep-

First, I do not understand how to set container registry through environment variable, am I supposed to give it a link??

Second, I've gone into Kaniko config guide and did everything as told -> creating config.json with `"auth":"mypassword for dockerhub"`. After that In the book it says:

> To make sure your docker installation is properly configured, you can write one line Dc and
> push it to your registry."

> Example 2.7 Specify the new container is built on top of Kubeflow's
> container

```
FROM gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/tensorflow-2.1.0-notebook-cpu:1.0.0
```

> Example 2.8 Build new container and push to registry for use

```
IMAGE="${CONTAINER_REGISTRY}/kubeflow/test:v1" 
docker build  -t "${IMAGE}" -f Dockerfile . docker push "${IMAGE}"
```

I've created `Dockerfile` with code from Example2.7 inside it, then ran code from Example 2.8 however not working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. You set the environment variable using `export CONTAINER_REGISTRY=docker.io/your_username` in your terminal (or in your `~/.bash_profile` and run `source ~/.bash_profile`).
2. Your `.docker/config.json` does not have your password in plain text but in base64, for example the output of `echo -n 'username:password' | base64`
3. The `docker build` and the `docker push` are two separate commands, in your example they're seen as one command, unlike the book.